# Is there an alternative for .bashrc for /bin/sh?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I need a script which is run on startup of `/bin/sh`, similar to `.bashrc` for `/bin/bash`. Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT:**

I tried both `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, I wrote `echo 'hello world'` to both files. None of these are working. When I type `sh` into the console, nothing pops up.

I am using ArchLinux.

Comment: You can use `~/.profile`

Comment: thanks, but it is not working

Comment: Arch Linux doesn't ship Bourne shell (which is a 1970s-era specification). Perhaps you're thinking of POSIX sh (which dates to the 90s)?

Comment: You can tell easily which one you're using: In Bourne, `^` is supported as a pipe character, whereas with POSIX-compliant `/bin/sh`, it's only `|`. So, does `echo hello ^ cat` emit the string `hello ^ cat` on its output (meaning you're on POSIX sh), or does it emit `hello` (meaning you're on Bourne)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, you are right, it is the POSIX sh.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Arch, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, which has quite a few rules about startup scripts, with special cases when called  `sh` :

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
>   behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, ...

If you start it from the console, without any command, i.e. as an interactive, non-login shell, you should use the `ENV` variable :

```
export ENV=~/.profile
sh
```

or

```
ENV=~/.profile sh
```

> When invoked as an **interactive [non login] shell with the name sh**, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is defined, and  uses the  expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.

Alternatively you can use the `--login` option to make it behave like a login shell, and read the `.profile` file.

```
sh --login
```

> When  invoked **as  an  interactive  login  shell [with the name sh]**,  or  a 
>   non-interactive  shell with the --login option, it first attempts to
>   read and execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that
>   order

Comment: I used this. All I had to do was to add the `--login` option. Although I am pretty sure this approach is philosophically incorrect in my case, it is working and I don't care. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I will assume, as is true on debian-ubuntu-like systems, that your `/bin/sh` is `dash`.

For dash, set the environment variable `ENV` to have the path to the initialization file of your choice.  This would be dash's analog to `~/.bashrc`.

If you are interested in login shells, `dash` reads `~/.profile`.

As an example, one could add to `~/.profile`:

```
ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV
```

This would cause `dash` to read `~/.shinit` when an interactive shell starts.

#### Edit

> "I tried both /etc/profile and ~/.profile, I wrote echo 'hello world'
>   to both files. None of these are working. When I type sh into the
>   console, nothing pops up."

Those files are *only* read for *login* shells.  If you just run `sh` at the command prompt, you are starting an *interactive* shell.

#### Documentation

From `man dash`:

> **Invocation**
>   If no args are present and if the standard input of
>   the shell is connected to a terminal (or if the -i flag is set), and
>   the -c option is not present,  the shell is considered an interactive
>   shell.  An interactive shell generally prompts before each command and
>   handles programming and command errors
>        differently (as described below).  When first starting, the shell inspects argument 0, and if it begins with a dash ‘-’, the shell is
>   also considered a
>        login shell.  This is normally done automatically by the system when the user first logs in.  A login shell first reads commands from
>   the files  /etc/profile and .profile if they exist.  If the
>   environment variable ENV is set on entry to an interactive shell, or
>   is set in the .profile of a login  shell, the shell next reads
>   commands from the file named in ENV.  **Therefore, a user should place
>   commands that are to be executed only at login time in the .profile
>   file, and commands that are executed for every interactive shell
>   inside the ENV file.**  To set the ENV variable to some file, place the
>   following line in your .profile of your home directory
>
> ```
>        ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV
> ```
>
> substituting for “.shinit” any filename you wish.
>
> If command line arguments besides the options have been specified,
>   then the shell treats the first argument as the name of a file from
>   which to read   commands (a shell script), and the remaining arguments
>   are set as the positional parameters of the shell ($1, $2, etc). 
>   Otherwise, the shell reads commands from its standard input. [Emphasis added.]

#### POSIX

From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html) (hat tip: [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)):

> **ENV**
>  This variable, when and only when an interactive shell is
>   invoked, shall be subjected to parameter expansion (see Parameter
>   Expansion) by the shell, and the resulting value shall be used as a
>   pathname of a file containing shell commands to execute in the current
>   environment. The file need not be executable. If the expanded value of
>   ENV is not an absolute pathname, the results are unspecified. ENV
>   shall be ignored if the real and effective user IDs or real and
>   effective group IDs of the process are different.

Comment: Note that `ENV` is part of the POSIX standard, not specific to `dash`. (Does `dash` even *have* any extensions to the standard?)

Comment: Will the `ENV` trick work if `.profile` is not interpreted for interactive shells?

Comment: @karlosss, that's the point of `export ENV`: it's inherited from your login shell by interactive shells run as children. Note that if you're going to `echo` something from your `ENV` script, you should check for whether the current shell is interactive first -- you'll break a bunch of programs (like rsync) by having your dotfiles emit content on stdout on noninteractive shells.

Comment: Sorry, maybe that is quite a newbie question, but how to get this work? When I type `sh`, nothing pops up. I have the "`ENV` trick" in my `~/.profile` file. The shell is interactive, the `$-` varialbe contains `i`.

Comment: @karlosss, well, have you actually logged out and back in, for your `.profile` to be run? Alternately `echo "$ENV"` reflect the intended value? If your `.profile` wasn't run on login, it's worth looking at your login shell if, for instance, it was bash and found `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` instead, your `.profile` may not be executed unless you source it from either of the other two [should they exist].

Comment: `$ENV` is empty, my login shell is probably bash, as you say. `sh` really has nothing like `.bashrc`? Does it have to be that complicated?

Comment: `ENV` is not a "trick"; it's a documented feature of all POSIX-compatible shells.

Comment: @karlosss In that case, put a line like `ENV=$HOME/.shinit; export ENV` in your `~/.bash_profile` also.  That should cover the waterfront.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the info POSIX.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

A quick (likely unsafe) hack to utilize the ENV feature to customize an rc within a docker file to be able to execute
something like `docker run -it ${image} sh`:

*Dockerfile*

```
ENV ENV /etc/env.sh
RUN echo "alias ll='ls -la'" >> "${ENV}"
```

(possibly unsafe as user can override value of ENV at container runtime)