# How to change the default /bin/sh to /bin/bash on opening CLI for selected container in Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

If I select any container and click CLI button, the `/bin/sh` shell will be opened by default. Is there any way to manually reconfigure Docker to open `/bin/bash`?

Comment: Not sure if there is an option but there is a command: `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash`

Comment: container command prompt must be installed before we can use it. you get /bin/sh terminal prompt because most of the container have  this shell environment by default. you can try any other container where bash is by default like Ubuntu or some other container?  i doubt that we can change that from Docker itself.

Comment: @anemyte Yes, I know, but it's more convenient for me to click the CLI link from Docker Desktop app.

Comment: Docker Desktop should just make this an option in the settings. In Visual Studio, the "Open in Terminal" option in the Containers tab uses bash by default.

Answer (score 8):

It will depend on the base image, you can build a custom image and add bash if it is not available. And link the create a link to use bash instead of sh

```sh
FROM <BASE_IMAGE>
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

RUN ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly answer you asked for but for me it works to type `bash` in sh terminal. It opens bash over the sh. Only nousance is that I must `exit` twice.

Answer (score 4):

I changed default shell into `bash` by making a new image with below `Dockerfile` commands.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM <parent image>

# make /bin/sh symlink to bash instead of dash:
RUN echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure dash

# set ENV to execute startup scripts
ENV ENV ~/.profile
```

and create a new image.

```bash
$ docker build --tag <image> .
```

1. change symbolic link of `/bin/sh` to `bash`

   https://superuser.com/questions/715722/how-to-do-dpkg-reconfigure-dash-as-bash-automatically
2. `source ~/.profile` file when executing `/bin/sh`

   [Is there an alternative for .bashrc for /bin/sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621880/is-there-an-alternative-for-bashrc-for-bin-sh)
3. If you want to clear `ENV` after startup, you may add below line to the `~/.bashrc` file. (**Be careful not to mess up other scripts**)

   ```
   unset ENV
   ```